# INSERT data From IBM i-series database table into SNOWFLAKE database table using Linked server connection

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, openquery, snowflake-schema

INSERT data From IBM i-series database (Created Linked server connection -SOFT) table into SNOWFLAKE database table (Created Linked server connection -SF_64)

**Linked server connection(Created in One of the SQL server)**
SOFT - linked server connection with IBM Iseries Database
SF_64 - linked server connection with IBM Iseries Database

```
INSERT INTO [SF_64].[PROD].[REPORTING].[DPMPPHY_SSIS_TESTING]
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SOFT, 'SELECT * FROM ABC.DPMPPHY')
```

Getting below error wile executing above query in SQL server

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SF_64" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SF_64". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Comment: Why? You are executing a query in one database engine that retrieves data from another (remote) engine in order to insert it into yet another (remote) engine. This makes little sense. I suggest you revisit the decisions that lead to this approach - linked servers are notoriously fragile, error-prone, and difficult to debug.

Comment: Already one of the process running and loading from ISeries DB to MS SQL server database. I want to use same process to load with cloud database(Snowflake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(SF_64,'SELECT * FROM REPORTING.DPMPPHY_SSIS_TESTING') SELECT *FROM OPENQUERY(SOFT,'SELECT * FROM ABC.DPMPPHY')
```